# request class not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple form which i want to submit in db. but its giving me error. 
Here is my CreateProductRequest Class

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateProductRequest extends FormRequest{
    //code here
}
```

And here is my controller function.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\PrivatePages;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Request\CreateProductRequest;
use App\Productuse Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\FormRequests;

class ProductController extends Controller{
    public function UpdateAdminProfile(CreateProductRequest $request){
        $saveproduct = new Product();
        $saveproduct->name = $request->name;
        $saveproduct->quantity =$request->description;

        $saveproduct->save();
     }
}
```

when i am trying to submit form it is giving me following error.

```
Class App\Http\Requests\Request\CreateProductRequest does not exist
```

Comment: You have typo error in your controller. Please read 4th line.         **use App\Productuse Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;**

Comment: It says `Class App\Http\Requests\Request\CreateProductRequest does not exist` on which file? Maybe you have namespace issues.

Comment: yes its like namespace issue but all namespaces is correctly defined and used

Comment: that is why i added my namespaces in question. may be some mistake in namespaces

Comment: no typo issue i just comment this line you have mentioned its same

Comment: my CreateProductRequest is exending From FormRequest

Comment: on Controller file

Answer (score 0):

If you have generated request properly by following command:

```
php artisan make:request ContactsRequest
```

Double check that you have a file named ContactsRequest.php under folder:

```
app/Http/Requests
```

If you have one under that folder you will be able to use your custom ContactsRequest in following way:

```
public function somefunction(Requests\ContactsRequest $request)
```

Comment: I have all files available in the directory

Comment: Have you run composer dump-autoload ?

Answer (score 0):

try to run `composer dump-autoload` on your laravel project directory.

also try this code

```
public function UpdateAdminProfile(CreateProductRequest $request) {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
      $saveproduct = new Product();
      $saveproduct->name = $request->name;
      $saveproduct->quantity =$request->description;

      $saveproduct->save();
      DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      DB::rollback();
    }

}
```

Do not forget to add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; before the class

Comment: now it just refreshes the browser and not submitting data in db.

Comment: okay, now try changing the $request->name and $request->description to $request->get('name') and $request->get('description');

Comment: same it just refreshes the browser

Comment: my CreateProductRequest is extended From FormRequest not Request

Comment: when i try to run my function without CreateProductRequest Class it is saving data in db. but without CreateProductRequest

Answer (score 0):

Change namespace to:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests
```

And in controller:

```
use App\Http\Requests\CreateProductRequest;
```

Comment: no , its not working just refreshes the browser. now it is not even going to route specified in form action

Comment: @raja it means it worked, you've fixed the error. The empty browser is the next issue you need to solve.

Comment: no its not working it just shows me the form which contains submit button and this form is to validate by CreateProductRequest.

Comment: @raja reread my previous comment. It means you've fixed `CreateProductRequest` related error and now you should fix the next one.